# Backbone.js - Adding keydown events when view is active?

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, javascriptmvc

I have a view called gallery that options. I want to listen and act on keydown events when the gallery is rendered (until it's closed).

How do I do this in backbone events? I've tried all variations of 'keydown X':function and none have worked.

Comment: Your gallery is backbone view or standalone html + js?

Comment: show us your selectors for `keydown` events... i think you binding them to wrong elements

Comment: It's just: events: { 'keypress':'doThis' }

Comment: No selectors. Listen to any keypress.

Comment: Try on render bind event to `$(document)` and on `.remove()` make `unbind()`

Comment: What do mean by *"a view called gallery that options"*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tested the following and it worked flawlessly:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ... snip ...
  events: {
    'keyup :input': 'logKey'
    ,'keypress :input': 'logKey'
  }
  ,logKey: function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.keyCode);
  }
});
```

I'd go back and check your code. All events in Backbone are defined as delegates attached to the `viewInstance.el` element. To unbind the events, call `viewInstance.remove()` which calls `$(viewInstance.el).remove()` under the covers and cleans up all the delegated events.

Also note that in some browsers (Firefox I believe) there's a known issue that some keys (like arrow keys) don't bubble and will not work properly with delegated `keypress` events. If you're catching special keys, you're probably better off using `keyup` and `keydown`.

Comment: Isn't this making assumptions that the View in question contains inputs? I think the OP was asking about the case where a particular view is simply rendered -- imagine that there is a lightboxed image or something and you wanted to hook up "Escape" to closing the image...

Comment: You are correct. My solution assumes there are input elements. If you wanted to act on key events anywhere in the view, you just exclude the selector (as the Backbone documentation states).

`events: {keyup: 'logKey'}`

Comment: - I can't get these global keypress/keyup/keydown to work. Is there some other minor detail that I must be forgetting? Could you possibly point to a reference or even a fiddle for more information of the document-wide events